# What is the best way to scale and fade a splash screen using libGDX, so that it is not stretched?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm creating a game in libGDX and I'm having a bit of trouble creating a splash screen with the `com.badlogic.gdx.Screen` class and the Universal Tween Engine. Basically my problem is making the image not stretched. What is the best way to do this? My code is as followed:

```
package com.trohrt.tothemoon.screens;

import aurelienribon.tweenengine.Tween;
import aurelienribon.tweenengine.TweenManager;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.trohrt.tothemoon.ttm;
import com.trohrt.tothemoon.tween.SpriteAccessor;

public class Splash implements Screen {

    private SpriteBatch batch;
    private Texture texture;
    private Sprite splash;
    private TweenManager tweenManager;
    private ttm ttm;

    public Splash(ttm ttm) {
        this.ttm = ttm;
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        batch.begin();
        splash.draw(batch);
        batch.end();

        tweenManager.update(delta);
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();

        tweenManager = new TweenManager();
        Tween.registerAccessor(Sprite.class, new SpriteAccessor());

        texture = new Texture("data/splash.png");
        splash = new Sprite(texture);

        Tween.set(splash, SpriteAccessor.ALPHA).target(0).start(tweenManager);
        Tween.to(splash, SpriteAccessor.ALPHA, 2).target(1).start(tweenManager);
        Tween.to(splash, SpriteAccessor.ALPHA, 2).target(0).delay(3).start(tweenManager);
    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {
        dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        batch.dispose();
        splash.getTexture().dispose();
    }

}
```

Currently I can get the image to appear and fade, but I want it to be centered, and not stuck in the bottom left corner of the window or stretched.

Comment: Can you add some code to your question?

Comment: Edited to add more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
splash.draw(batch);
```

you can call

```
batch.draw(
    splash,
    Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2f - splash.getRegionWidth() / 2f,
    Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2f - splash.getRegionHeight() / 2f,
    splash.getRegionWidth(),
    splash.getRegionHeight()
 );
```

To avoid stretching on screen resize, add this :

```
@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    batch.getProjectionMatrix().setToOrtho2D(0, 0, width, height);
}
```

To allow fading add this just after `batch.begin();` :

```
batch.setColor(splash.getColor());
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This centers it the way I want it, but it gets rid of the fade animation and when I resize the window, the image gets stretched.